# How to display Story in Storybook

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, storybook

### Summery

I"ve tried to implement Storybook in Nuxt.js application.
I successed to run Storybook. And I wrote `index.vue` and `index.stories.ts`.
But Storybook does not show any Story.

[image]

So I want to know how to actually display Story.

### Show some code

index.vue

```html
<template>
  <nuxt-link to="https://nuxtjs.org">
    NuxtJs
  </nuxt-link>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'nuxt-property-decorator'

@Component({})
export default class TestComponent extends Vue {}
</script>
```

index.stories.ts

```js
import Test from './index.vue'

export default {
  component: Test,
  title: 'Components/Test'
}

export const Component = () => ({
  components: { Test },
  template: '<Test />'
})
```

Also I wrote `./storybook/config.js` for settings.

```js
import { configure } from '@storybook/vue';

const req = require.context('../components', true, /.stories.ts$/);
function loadStories() {
  req.keys().forEach(filename => {
    return req(filename)
  });
}

configure(loadStories, module);
```

Here is the actual repository. Please check.
https://github.com/jpskgc/nuxt-sample/tree/storybook-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this problem by adding `.storybook/main.js` instead of `.storybook/config.js`.

```js
module.exports = {
  stories: ['../components/**/*.stories.ts'],
};
```

https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/next/MIGRATION.md#deprecated-configure